# Word parsing in Latin declensions

Tags: etymology

I'm trying to parse a few sets of Latin words divided into the categories: perfect participle, present participle and gerundives.

I'm struggling a bit. Particularly with gerundives. For instance, in *explicandum* I know that *um* seems to be a singular ending, neuter. *ex* is out; *plic* is to fold, but I keep finding **and** as in *memorandum*, but I'm not quite sure how to parse it. I think that there is a thematic vowel in there. On the whole, I'm supposed to parse it, provide the gloss of the elements and a meaning of the word, but I'm not able to parse the *and*in the gerundives. Is a single element or can I break it down further? Suggested readings are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wanted to break *explicāndum* down into morphemes, it would look something like

```
ex -plicā-nd -um
out-fold -GND-NOM.SG.N
"it should be unfurled"
```

The *-nd-* in the middle marks the gerund and gerundive. I would personally group the *-ā-* in with the verb stem instead of with the gerundive suffix, but an argument could be made either way on that.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  I keep finding - and or - end in the gerundive set. It makes sense that - nd is a gerundive marker (sort of).